# Select row with one column for each row in another select

Tags: postgresql, pivot

An existing query returns the following table:

| UserID | Sector | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 111 |
| 1 | 2 | 122 |
| 1 | 3 | 133 |
| 2 | 2 | 222 |
| 2 | 3 | 233 |
| 3 | 1 | 311 |

But I would like to "reformat" it in the following way:

| UserID | Sector 1 | Sector 2 | Sector 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 | 122 | 122 |
| 2 |  | 222 | 233 |
| 3 | 311 |  |  |

The maximum number of sectors is variable. Since i am new to SQL I am not sure weather this would be something DB Type Specific, so a solution which works for PostgreSQL is appreciated.

If this is something which should not be done in the database, it is also okay. I am still figuring out what to do in the database and what not.

Title is not good, I know. Please make some recommendation if you have an more precise one.

Comment: Search this site for *pivot rows to columns*. This sort of question has been asked and answered here many times before.

Comment: While pivoting can be done in the DB it is NOT recommended. This is a task much more suited for your apps presentation manager.  Further. as @user15411679 points out you cannot pivot  a dynamic number of columns in a static query.  The query must contain exactly the columns being pivoted.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot have dynamic number of columns.
Here is the SQL for the sample data you've provided. You must have tablefunc extension installed.

```
SELECT *
FROM crosstab(
  'select userid, sector, value
   from user_sector
   order by 1,2')
AS ct(userid int, sector1 int, sector2 int,sector3 int);
```